# ffmpeg - Zoompan IN and Out alternately

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to apply a Zoompan effect but instead of zoom in or zoom out, I'd like to mix both of them: the zoom will start with zoom in, and, after some period of time, the zoom continue with zoom out, and so on, alternatively.

While I'm thinking how to archieve this, has someone some tips?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You need to use state e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i src.png
 -vf zoompan=d=300:z='if(gte(zoom,2)+eq(ld(1),1)*gt(zoom,1),zoom-0.04*st(1,1),zoom+0.04+0*st(1,0))'
o.mp4
```

This expression zooms from `zoom=1` to `zoom=2` in steps of `0.04`. Remember, zoom is initialized to `1`. The above will create 6 loops.

In `st`(store) and `ld`(load) functions, the first argument is variable id (0 to 9), and the second is the value.

Comment: good, it works, but I don't understand very well  what does it do! What if I'd like to start with zoom out and then zoom in? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I use  pzoom for z evaluazion `min(pzoom+0.0015,1.5)`, and before zoompan I scale the image with `scale=iw*10:ih*10`. I'm trying to apply your formula, but it does not work. How should I change to use pzoom?

Comment: Sorry, it works well; I have updated my ffmpeg version with 3.4.2. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Gyan How can this effect be done in videos, with it zooming into the center?

Comment: `d=1` and use `pzoom` in place of `zoom`

Comment: @pigeonburger check this you may adapt it for a video : https://superuser.com/questions/1087685/ffmpeg-zoompan-image-to-center-position

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gyan's answer, here are more details.

The following creates a video from an image and an mp3 with an infinite zoom-in-out on the image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png  -i adio.mp3 -vf "[0:v]scale=7680x4320,zoompan=z='if(gte(zoom,1.5)+eq(ld(1),1)*gt(zoom,1),zoom-0.00005*st(1,1),zoom+0.00005+st(1,0))':d=20000" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest out3.mp4
```

`[0:v]scale=7680x4320` upscales 4 times the original 1920x1080 image for a smooth transition.

`d=20000` specifies the duration of the zoom-in-out. In this case, I perform a zoom from 1 to 1.5 with increments or decrements of 0.00005. That's (1.5-1) / 0.00005 steps for the zoom, which means I need two times this for the zoom + dezoom, which is 10'000*2 = 20'000.

`if(gte(zoom,1.5)+eq(ld(1),1)*gt(zoom,1),zoom-0.00005*st(1,1),zoom+0.00005+st(1,0))` can be translated to the following pseudo-code:

```
// '||' corresponds to a `+` and '&&' to a '*' 
if zoom >= 1.5 || (isDezooming && zoom > 1) {
  zoom-0.00005
  isDezooming = true // corresponds to '*st(1,1)'
} else {
  zoom+0.00005
  isDezooming = false // corresponds to '+st(1,0)'
}
```

where `isDezooming` corresponds to the variable `1` handled with the `ld(1)` and `st(1,0)` instructions. Here is the full [list of instruction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).